# DNS record configuration to work with server blocks and virtual hosts

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, apache-virtualhost

What is the correct DNS configuration for multiple subdomain names, so that they will work with nginx server blocks and/or Apache virtual hosts?

Example:

Server IP Address: 192.0.2.0
Main/primary subdomain name: vegetable.example.com

Other subdomain names to be served by this rig:

- artichoke.example.com
- bean.example.com
- carrot.example.com

How to properly configure the DNS records to work with Apache virtual hosts or nginx server blocks?

- A record?
- CNAME?
- Alias?

Comment: Within `example.com` you declare a NS record for each of the subdomains and within them, you create `A` records just as you normally would for `example.com`. It's really not difficult, just remember to get the SOA correct. For reverse, you just list all the hosts against the single IP address.

Comment: Many DNS services allow you to define an A record with the wildcard name `*.example.com` so any undefined subdomain uses the default IP address. Nginx and Apache don't care if your domain names are defined as A or CNAME records - it's the browser's job to use DNS to resolve the domain into an IP address.